# Using PHP to extract data from an ATOM feed and using it reverse lookup coordinates to an actual address

Tags: php, atom-feed, google-latitude

Basically I have a public feed: http://www.google.com/latitude/apps/badge/api?user=-1671995934285587708&type=atom

If you go to my Google Profile you can see it says: "Gareth is in 6 Seaside Gardens, Mullaloo WA 6027, Australia (1 minute ago)" google.com/profiles/Gareth.B.Hall

How can I, using PHP, display my location on a website the same way it's displayed on my Google Profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask Google's [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for information about the location. The details are all in that link; you could use an URL like:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=-31.774891,115.735698&sensor=false

The value that you probably want would be the `formatted_address` of `6 Seaside Gardens, Mullaloo WA 6027, Australia`.